# How does iptables recognize packet state?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, administration

Consider these two sets of rules:

Set A

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Set B

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Previously I was under the impression that the two were functionally the same, however someone recently remarked to me:

> To have an **ESTABLISHED,RELATED** connection you have to have a rule that add the   connection into the db that this rule looks at. This is done with the **NEW** rule. Once the connection is accepted it is placed into the db so the **ESTABLISHED,RELATED** rules can match against it. Without the **NEW** rules nothing is laced into the db and thus **ESTABLISHED,RELATED** will never match anything.

So I admit I'm a bit confused as to how the internals of `iptables` operate, exactly how does `iptables` go about tagging packets based on the packet state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[I unfortunately had to remove references from the below due to the disappearance of `iptables.info` so you may have to trust me on a couple of points.]*

> Without the NEW rules nothing is laced into the db and thus ESTABLISHED,RELATED will never match anything.

**This is false.**

There are five userland states (there are more in kernel space), and while an ESTABLISHED or RELATED connection does logically need to begin with a NEW packet, you do not need any explicit NEW rule to produce such a connection (you do need an explicit ACCEPT which *implicitly* includes NEW packets, however).  Follow the logic and consider the other four states first, eg.:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-prohibited
```

I've left out NOTRACK since that can only exist because of a previous `iptables` rule. Guess what's left after these rules have been applied?  Only NEW packets.  You can now sort those however you want.  It will work, I promise, and note: *with no NEW rules at all*.  None.

> Exactly how does iptables go about tagging packets based on the packet state?

A connection is established once a reply has been sent. The nature of the protocol evidently comes into play here a bit (the kernel applies those rules too); e.g. when a NEW SYN TCP packet is accepted a SYN/ACK is sent in reply and the connection is ESTABLISHED; following a final FIN/ACK it is defunct.

How a connection is considered RELATED evidently depends further on the protocol involved; basically it relates to connections to/from hosts that already have an ESTABLISHED connection.  Notice that you must sometimes load special modules (e.g., for ftp) in order to get this to work.

Comment: Perfect answer, comprehendable and well referenced, thanks a lot

Comment: https://iptables.info appears to be down, and possibly no longer available, and so the above, `iptables.info` references are broken. Are there any suitable, substitute references? ( @goldilocks )

Comment: Yes, I think iptables.info is gone for good.  Glad I downloaded it at some point.  I don't know of anything like that online.  If you are looking for a well written, compact reference *The Linux Iptables Pocket Reference* (G. N. Purdy) is worth having.

Comment: Pretty sure the guy who wrote iptables.info also distributed it as a book, but the only contact is that domain (`support@iptables.info`).  However, just noticed it's licensed under the GNU Free Documentation License, so I could redistribute it...